# Static bootstrap navbar don't go 100% width on smaller screens

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

guys I'm having a problem in my `navbar`. In smaller screens the navbar don't span to full width. here's my code:

```css
nav.navbar {
  background-color: black;
  /* top: 0;
        margin: 0; */
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  width: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #333333;
}

div.navbar-collapse {
  background-color: black;
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-xl static-top">
  <button class="navbar-toggler hamburguer" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <div class="menu-icon">
                <div class="bar"></div>
                <div class="bar mid"></div>
                <div class="bar"></div>
            </div>
            </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
    <div class="navbar-nav options links">
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="https://www.sfdergedg.com/about.php">About</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="https://www.sfdergedg.com/blog.php">Blog</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="https://www.sfdergedg.com/media.php">Media</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="https://www.sfdergedg.com/meet_the_dev.php">Meet the Dev!</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="https://www.sfdergedg.com/support.php">Support</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="https://www.sfdergedg.com/contacts.php">Contacts</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I've seen problems about this but nothing solved my problem. Seem's this problem is common when we use a static navbar.

thank you in advance! ;)

Comment: Where's your media query for smaller screens?

Comment: Is your navbar wrapped in a parent element?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `margin` and `padding` to `0px` for `body` tag.

Below is working demo:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav.navbar {
  background-color: black;
  width: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #333333;
}


div.navbar-collapse {
  background-color: black;
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-xl static-top">
  <button class="navbar-toggler hamburguer" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <div class="menu-icon">
                <div class="bar"></div>
                <div class="bar mid"></div>
                <div class="bar"></div>
            </div>
            </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
    <div class="navbar-nav options links">
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="https://www.sfdergedg.com/about.php">About</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="https://www.sfdergedg.com/blog.php">Blog</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="https://www.sfdergedg.com/media.php">Media</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="https://www.sfdergedg.com/meet_the_dev.php">Meet the Dev!</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="https://www.sfdergedg.com/support.php">Support</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="https://www.sfdergedg.com/contacts.php">Contacts</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that bootstraps css already has a margin of 0 set to the body tag

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that below navbar I had an Image without width set. And as it was wider than the screen, the navbar didn't span at 100%. It fixed after I set the width of that Image to 100% or less. Thank you for all answers! ;)

Best Regards,
Eduardo